# Ejabbred loger error

Tags: logging, ejabberd

I know this issue was raised few times but I didn't found a solution yet. I cant use the logger
 Downloaded & compile eJabrred with the code from https://github.com/processone/ejabberd.git
 My code:

```
-module(mod_hello).
-behavior(gen_mod).
-include("ejabberd.hrl").
-include("lager.hrl").
-include("jlib.hrl").
export([
    start/2,
    stop/1
]).

start(_Host, _Opt) ->
       ?DEBUG("Loaded mode_hello", []).        
stop(_Host) ->
        ok.
```

Error:

```
13:15:27.670 [critical] Problem starting the module mod_hello for host <<"localhost">> 
options: []
error: undef
[{p1_logger,info_msg,
            [mod_hello,16,"Loading module 'mod_hello' ",[]],
            []},
{gen_mod,start_module,3,[{file,"src/gen_mod.erl"},{line,82}]},
{lists,foreach,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1336}]},
{ejabberd_app,start,2,[{file,"src/ejabberd_app.erl"},{line,67}]},
{application_master,start_it_old,4,
                     [{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,272}]}]
13:15:27.671 [critical] ejabberd initialization was aborted because a     module start failed.
```

Tried also to rebeat:

```
./rebar get-deps 
./rebar compile
cp -R deps/* /lib/ejabberd/include/
```

but with the same error.

also when I'm trying to compile & run mod_echo everything is OK, but when I'm adding a new line with msg_info I get the same error as in my mode_hello.
Any ideas

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to include lager, but need to include: logger.hrl.

Comment: It is logger.hrl and it need to be build and configure with lager support (The default) and be place in your ejabberd src directory.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which version of ejabberd you are using and how you build it, but it seems you are missing p1_logger code. ejabberd installer package it and when building from source the code is automatically pulled and build from that repository: https://github.com/processone/p1_logger

It seems you have an issue with your installation.